# JQuery Remove Parent Elements

Tags: jquery, html, hide

I have some third party HTML that looks like this:

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblURL" AssociatedControlID="txtURL" 
                  runat="server" EnableViewState="false" CssClass="FieldLabel" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <cms:CMSTextBox ID="txtURL" runat="server" 
                  CssClass="TextBoxField" EnableViewState="false"
                  MaxLength="450" ProcessMacroSecurity="false" />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I am not allowed to change this HTML. I want to hide this label and input tag and have figured out how to do that in JQuery with this code:

```
$('label[id$="lblURL"]').hide();
$('input[id$="txtURL"]').hide();
```

This effectively hides the elements from the page. Problem is that the parent  and  elements still remain. How can remove the tr and td elements?

Comment: btw in case anyone wants to know, the reason I am using the jquery selector that "ends" with a given ID being specified, it is because the CMS in question adds a bunch of stuff in front of the ID that is actually rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your label and input box are always in an enclosing table row, so you can hide the whole table row:

```
$('label[id$="lblURL"]').closest('tr').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the `TR` completely

```
$('tr [id$="lblURL"]').closest('tr').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using .remove instead of hide, `$('#element').parent.remove();`